# Error while inserting in a table containing identity column System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, exception, ado.net-entity-data-model

In my ASP.Net MVC 4 project I'm trying to insert data into a table which has identity an auto-increment column (ACTIVITYID), which is the Primary Key.

**Table Class**

```
public partial class ACTIVITY
{
    public decimal ACTIVITYID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> CALLTICKETNUMBER { get; set; }
    public string ACTION { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> STATUSIDATTHETIMEOFACTION { get; set; }
    public short RECORDFORDISPLAY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ACTIVITYDATE { get; set; }
    public string USER_ { get; set; }

    public virtual CALLTICKET CALLTICKET { get; set; }
}
```

**Upon calling the following method generates exception**

```
    public static void AddActivity(long ticketNumber, string action, string userId, int? previousStatusId = null)
    {

            var newActivity = new ACTIVITY
            {
                ACTION = action,
                ACTIVITYDATE = System.DateTime.Now,
                CALLTICKETNUMBER = ticketNumber,
                STATUSIDATTHETIMEOFACTION = previousStatusId,
                 USER_ = userId,
            };
            dbOraContext.ACTIVITies.Add(newActivity);
            dbOraContext.SaveChanges();

    }
```

While viewing **ACTIVITies.Add(newActivity)** ACTIVITYID is inserting with value 0.

On tracing the inner exception following exception is displayed:

**{"ORA-00001: unique constraint (ATM_CRM.PK_ACTIVITY) violated"}**

Also, an exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred.

Earlier I have worked with MS SQL Server, and never encountered such a problem. Auto-increment column should automatically get its value.

Note that I'm working on Oracle DB.

Comment: This is Entity Framework, right? Are you using Code First or DB First with EDMX generated model? Depending on the method creating the model class, the primary key field should be marked accordingly.

Comment: I'm using Database First approach. The above class is the database table class which is auto-generated while adding table using entity data model.

Comment: I see that you're not adding `[Key]` attribute on the `ACTIVITYID` property. Try adding it from T4 template file and set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity` if it's autoincrement column.